# Spring java One to One relationship reassigning entity to owner

Tags: java, spring, jpa, one-to-one

I have an entity A related one to one to B.
I created a foreign key: A.b_id <==> B.id

With

```
 A { @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @JoinColumn(name = "b_id") private B b; }
```

At some point, I do A.setB(new B());

But then I want to be able to change it to => A.setB(new B2());

On doing so, I got below error:

```
update A set ....., b_id=? where id=? []; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

`b_id` has a constraint not null.

The mapping looks like

```
A { 
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id") 
    private B b; 
}
```

Comment: Can you please show the source code of your entities A and B. Do you have any cascading defined?

Comment: I have this:

A {
    @OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
    private B b;

}